# file not found - running a file located on flashdrive through CMD with e:\ command

Tags: file, cmd, boot

I've recently watched a video on youtube that runs a batch file from his flashdrive while on boot mode in the computer, though the quality was bad, I could see he was doing something like e:\ and then the file but when I try to do this, even through cmd on the desktop, it kept showing me

```
C:\Users\username>e:\hack   //the command
File not found - files   //the error
```

Here's the code I was trying to run:

```
@echo off
:: variables

SET odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
set backupcmd=xcopy /s /c /d /e /h /i /r /y
%backupcmd% "%drive%\files" "C:\Users\%USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

pause
```

the `pause` is just to see whether there are any errors or not.

Comment: Please explain shortly and clear what he/she wanted to do in the youtube video you saw. Share a link if possible. What is the value of `odrive` and `drive` environment variables? Edit your question to include this important information.

Comment: the goal was to run this through boot mode and without ay need for the password, be able to plant a file inside the pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in batch file is not working because of referencing with `%odrive:~0,2%` the first two characters of the environment variable `odrive` which is not defined at all, at least not in the batch file itself. And `"%drive%\files"` references the value of environment variable `drive` which is also not defined in the batch file.

The entire not working batch file as posted can be replaced by:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~d0\files" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\" /C /D /E /H /I /Q /R /Y >nul
```

Some comments on this single command line:

1. `%~d0` is replaced during execution by drive letter and colon of the batch file containing this single command line.
2. There must be a subdirectory `files` with the files and folders to copy in root directory of the drive containing the batch file.
3. It does not really make sense to copy files and folders from a USB storage media into the user's Windows **Start** menu in folder `Startup` for automatic start on Windows start after user login which should contain only *.lnk files. Such an approach is used by malware writers, but not by reliable programmers and their applications.
4. The options `/E` and `/S` should be used never at the same time. `/S` is for copying all files with subfolders, but without empty subfolders. `/E` is for copying all files with all subfolders including empty subfolders. So it does not make sense to specify both at the same time. `/E` is used in this case by **XCOPY**.
5. On destination being a directory the destination path should end with a backslash making it 100% clear for **XCOPY** that the destination is a directory. The option `/I` is not really needed on specifying destination directory with `\` at end.
6. `@` at beginning of the single command line prevents the display of this command line before executing it by `cmd.exe` which executes the batch file like `@echo off` does for all commands in a batch file.

For even better understanding the used command line and how it works, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~d0`
- `xcopy /?`

See also the list of predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Comment: thank you very much for your help!